# Make "watch later" always appear for YouTube videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-watch-later

During the day I add YouTube videos to my "watch later" queue and watch them at night on my Google TV. Sometimes the "watch later" button is visible in the preview pane (the little watch in the lower right hand corner) but sometimes it isn't. In this case I have to play the video, *then* add to my "watch later" list.

Below is an example from my Google Reader feed. I have to play to see the "watch later" button.

[image]

Can I make the "watch later" button always visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure but it depends on how the particular video is embedded from YouTube. You will see videos embedded in various different ways and dimensions.

Some videos are available for viewing at 240p while watched in YouTube but not when you watch the same video through some other site where it is embedded.

There is no such setting which makes the "Watch Later" button appear all the time. Also, as you are seeing the videos in a Google Reader Feed (or some other similar feeds/blogs), you are not even logged in to YouTube at all! Even if such a setting exists how can it be applied when you are not logged in at all?

P.S: Logging into one of the Google Service at a time does not means that you are logged into all the Google Services you use with the Account. Suppose you log into Google+ for four days and never open GMail during this period at all - in the GMail "Previous Login History" (at the end of your GMail Page") there will be no record of you logging in at all.

Comment: This was my suspicion. Thanks for the lesson!